# Upgrade Joomla 2.5 to 3.x

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Trying to upgrade Joomla 2.5.14 to latest Joomla 3.x. Have a backup and already setup "Short Term Support STS". Made sure allow_url_fopen = on and allow_url_include= off. But still not getting the update. Says I already have the latest version. Anyone have any ideas on this issue?

Thanks!

**OK, so resolved issue**. Using STS was no good, going to extension upload was no good, so went the classic way of uploading Joomla 3 stable package zip to replace Joomla 2.5 files. But before doing that, I disabled every non-core Joomla plugin and set a default Joomla template before dropping the upgrade files. After that, the dashboard was looking messed up, so went to Extensions manager > Manage > and used "Discover" + "Database". Changed the admin template to a Joomla 3 template. And now everything seems to be back to normal, but there seems a long way to updating plugins/components. STS and extension upload to upgrade is still not working.. so I guess I'm stuck with manual upgrade.

Comment: The classic extension > install is not working either. Getting "There was an error uploading this file to the server."

Comment: Probably the File Size Upload Limit on the server is set too low to disallow upload of larger files. By default PHP allows files up to 2 MB, try with 4 MB to solve it.

Comment: Updated upload limit on php.ini, but it's still showing as 2M on php information.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see latest available version, Go to:

- Extensions>Extension Manager>Update Tab
- Purge Cache
- Extensions>Extension Manager>Discover Tab
- Purge cache
- Extensions>Extension Manager>Database Tab
- If Errors in DB, Click the 'Fix' button

Go back to Components>Joomla Update
Set Options>Update Server to STS

You should be able to see latest version now.

Also, before upgrading, go to Extensions>Extension Manager>Warnings and check there aren't any alerts

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This actually forces the latest STS version (in this case Joomla 3.x) show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try the button "Purge cache", clear your browser’s cache, and check again for an update. Having said that, it is [discouraged to do so](http://docs.joomla.org/Why_is_my_Joomla!_2.5_site_update_manager_showing_an_update_to_3.x?) in most cases:

> you should not upgrade from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.x unless you are
>   certain that all of your additionally installed extensions (from third
>   party developers), especially templates, are Joomla 3.x ready or have
>   a Joomla 3.x version that you can upgrade to.

Comment: Nope. no luck either. Still showing that Joomla is up to date.

Comment: It is not discouraged at all, you just need to do that checking. That's like saying telling people to do a back up is discouraging them.

Comment: Not at all, backups are never discouraged :) It is discouraged to upgrade unless you are sure it is safe to do it i.e. all extensions are compatible with 3.x version.